# How to set variable from MAX and group?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, group-by, max

I have problem with selecting selecting SQL Max and group syntax then set it to variable. I have no problem from just selecting the MAX score. But Id like to echo the user that own that score and id to redirect to his profile page

This is my Database

```
-----------------------------
  id  |  user   |  score | justplayed
   1  | player1 | 1000   | 1
   2  | player2 | 1000   | 0
```

PHP code

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(score) AS max_score FROM score GROUP BY score WHERE justplayed > 0 ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $highscore = $row["max_score"];
            $highscoreowner = $row["user"];
            $highscoreownerid = $row["id"];
        }
    }
```

Html Code

```
Player of the day
<? echo $highscoreowner; ?>
Score
<? echo $highscore; ?><br>
<a href="profile.php?id=<? echo $highscoreownerid; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only selecting the max score in the SQL query, so you can't extract the other values in PHP. If you're looking for the entire row where the score is highest, then use this query instead:

```
SELECT score, user, id
FROM score
WHERE justplayed > 0
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This will take all the rows, order them from highest to lowest score, and then return only the first row.